# Custom HTML for each page - AWS S3/CloudFront

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, web, static

I have a static site on AWS S3/CloudFront. On every html page on my site, I want to add a google tag manager code:

/head
`<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src= 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f); })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');</script>`

/body
`<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>`

Is there a way to do this using AWS, rather than editing each page separately?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it dynamically, for each request, you can use [lambda@edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) or [cloudfront functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/) probably. But I think the best way would be to actually modify your source files in S3.